# bind("dragenter dragover drop") doesn't work in jQuery 1.7.1?

Tags: jquery, events, bind, drag

I have this function. It works great with jQuery 1.3.2. 
When I change to jQuery 1.6.4 it still works.

But **since jQuery 1.7.1**, it doesn't work anymore.

I don't understand why. Help please.

```
$("#upload").bind('dragenter dragover drop mousemove', function (e) {

        e.originalEvent.stopPropagation();
        e.originalEvent.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: why you come to conclusion that it not work?http://jsbin.com/elotoq/1/edit - here you can see that log is written when mouseover

Answer (score 1):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document.

Comment: With `.bind()`, `.live()` and `.on()` it doesn't work... since jQuery 1.7